# What are the icons for bluetooth devices shown in bluetooth scan menu?

Tags: bluetooth, samsung-galaxy-s7

In android bluetooth scan menu, the scanned devices are given various icons which specify the type of device that they are reporting themselves to be

[image]

What are device types 1 and 2 shown in this picture, and where can I get a list of all possible device types and their icons? Is this icon list specific to a smartphone or is it from the default android?

This screenshot is from Samsung galaxy s7 with android 8.0.0

Edit: or is there any way to probe for this information through adb or something?

Edit2: for anyone interested I downloaded an app called [Bluetooth scanner](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pzolee.bluetoothscanner&hl=en&gl=US) and it shows device 1 as "Unknown". So may be that's just what this icon means.

Comment: Similar to this question: https://eu.community.samsung.com/t5/other-smartphones/bluetooth-decice-symbols/td-p/769777 Also the icons match my Samsung S9/Android 10 but not my Google Pixel 2. Just a guess (2) appears be headphones (headphone case?) as for (1) some other bluetooth pairing - e.g. my Google Daydream controller.

Comment: @MorrisonChang is the list of icons and their meanings for android default/google pixel available anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

From my best searching, you can find a list of what devices would be possible in the Android documentation. It provides both a list of the [major device categories](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothClass.Device.Major) and [a more detailed listing of all possible devices](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothClass.Device). I'd imagine it's up to each device to report what it is.

I couldn't find a good reference for each image and these constants.

If you happen to be on Linux, you can use something like [`bluez-tools`](https://github.com/khvzak/bluez-tools) to see a device's icon from you command-line:

List devices known to your adapter.

```
bt-device -l

Added devices:
my-phone (A1:A1:A1:A1:A1:A1)
...
AB-AB-AB-AB-AB-AB (AB:AB:AB:AB:AB:AB)
```

Take the address of `my-phone` and pull up its data, here's a snippet from my phone's:

```
bt-device -i A1:A1:A1:A1:A1:A1

[A1:A1:A1:A1:A1:A1]
Name: my-phone
Icon: phone <- Used to pick an icon
Paired: 1
Trusted: 1
...
```

Here's the `icon` from a pair of wireless headphones I have:

```
bt-device -i ...

Name: Indy
Icon: audio-headset
```